# Where's the legend for the status icons?

Tags: 8.0, icons

You know, the icons that show your cellular strength, data connection type, wiffy, and stuff like that?  Its in that area at the top you can see when you swipe down from the top of your screen?  The words, they escape me.

I remember on my 7.1 HTC you had to go into settings, click through somewhere (About?) and that led you to a legend that listed the meanings of all those icons, but I can't seem to find it for 8.

Am I just stroking out, or am I right that it isn't there?  And if it does exist, where the heck is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a [list of icons](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-AU/how-to/wp8/basics/what-do-the-icons-on-my-phone-mean) with their meaning explained. Far more in-depth than anything you'll find in a phone. Hope it helps!

- http://www.windowsphone.com/en-AU/how-to/wp8/basics/what-do-the-icons-on-my-phone-mean